# Dart Editor Update failed: Unable to shutdown Analysis Server

Tags: dart

So after some time of completely letting my Dart project rest, I started Darteditor again. First, I check if the project still runs when I debug it - it does. Secondly, I check for updates:[image: Update Available]

Now I press the Button "Apply Update" and the following happens.
This is how it looked like before I clicked the button:
[image]

And this is after clicking it:
[image]

So **what is that Analysis Server that is Inactive** is my first question. But my more important one is **how do I update?**
Because pressing "No, I'll do it later" will simply close the error message and "Yes, download again" results in this:
[image]

I tried googling the problem and searched it on here - nothing found.
I also tried to find out where the corrupt already downloaded update is stored, so I could try to delete it - but I couldn't find out.

I assume that I am not the only one with this problem, so here I ask. Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/

> As of 1.11, Dart Editor is obsolete and no longer supported. We
>   recommend using DartPad to play with Dart and WebStorm to develop with
>   Dart. For more information, see the [announcement](http://news.dartlang.org/2015/04/the-present-and-future-of-editors-and.html).

Comment: Wow. How could I not find such an announcement?! Thank you very much. Which Editor would you recommend personally? Do you have any experience in transferring projects from darteditor to a new one?

Comment: @lucidbrot There is a  Dart plugin for Eclipse https://www.dartlang.org/tools/eclipse-plugin/ it might be the easiest way. But it  lacks some functionality. Or you can get WebStorm https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/dart-support.html

Comment: Thank you :) I have a new issue (a difference between the Dartium version and the Pub-build version). Do you think this is dartEditors fault and a switch would solve it or is Pub its own thing?