# Export a DartEditor project to Webstorm

Tags: dart

Because DartEditor is not supported anymore according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072620/dart-editor-update-failed-unable-to-shutdown-analysis-server) I tried to open the project in the Webstorm Trial version. But it does not work like it used to in DartEditor ... I am not exactly sure what my problem ist, which is bad, i know. sorry.

For example it does not find my icons from [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and delivers the following Error:

> GET http://localhost:63342/styles/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css 404 (Not Found)

This results in the icons of font-awesome not being displayed but the preset hamburger works - this also happened with the JS-built version in DartEditor, but with webstorm it also happens when I run it in chromium.
Also, when I run it with webstorm, it cannot communicate with the local server, which it can in DartEditor.

So...many problems, that may or may not have the same reason. Thus, I wonder if you could offer me an example on how to properly transfer a Dart-Project from DartEditor to Webstorm.

**EDIT**: Not being able to reach the server was because I had

> header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080');

in my php files. Sorry for bothering you with that.
My other problems have not much to do with the IDE so...**should I delete this or do you think others will make the same mistakes and need my question?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems:
1. Not being able to reach the server was because I had

> header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080');

in my php files.

2. In DartEditor, the following worked

> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

But in the other IDEs, I have to skip the first slash

> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`